# Calling an SQL stored procedure that's defined in a method using button click on form c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, forms

Having a lot of trouble with this. I'm working on a large project, so there's only a few classes I'm interested in and working on. Basically, these are forms - one is a main editor where a user edits details and the other is used to assign a pin number. In the main editor form, if the user has a pin, they can choose to edit this pin. Here's where my problem lies - if I edit the pin, what I'm doing in the code is deleting the old pin and adding the new one. However, the database doesn't update until AFTER the editor form is closed. Therefore, I'd like to call the method that does change the database on the OKButton click, if I could. The problem I'm facing is I don't know how.

Here is the DB code, we'll say the class is called DetailsConn:

```
public string editPin(int driverID)
{
        if (SchemaChecker.PINAvailable())
        {
            string sql = "EditPIN";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, base.connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Remove("@nDriverID");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nDriverID", driverID);
                cmd.Parameters.Remove("@nPIN");
                SqlParameter pinParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@nPIN", SqlDbType.Char);
                pinParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                pinParameter.Size = 32;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return pinParameter.Value.ToString();
            }
        }

        return "";
}
```

Here's the code for my edit:

```
private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (this.listViewDriverTags.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = this.listViewDriverTags.SelectedItems[0];

            DriverTag driverTag = lvi.Tag as DriverTag;

            else if (blahTag.blahType == 2)
            {
                buttonAssignPIN_Click(sender, e);
            }

            //message stuff and dialog boxes with localization info
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.listViewDriverTags.Items.Remove(lvi);
                if (Tag.id != -1)
                {
                    TagsToBeDeleted.Add(driverTag);
                }
            }

            if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                this.listViewTags.Items.Clear();
                this.listViewTags.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my buttonAssignPIN stuff:

```
private void buttonAssignPIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (AssignPINForm form = new AssignPINForm())
        {
            if (form.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DriverTag PIN = DriverTag.GetNewPIN(form.DriverTag);

                ListViewItem lvi = this.listViewTags.Items.Add(PIN.driverTag);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(this.TagTypes[PIN.TagType]);
                lvi.Tag = PIN;
            }
        }
 }
```

And finally, here's my AssignPINForm code:

```
public partial class AssignPINForm : Form
{
    public AssignPINForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.buttonOK.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOK_Click);
        this.buttonCancel.Click += new EventHandler(buttonCancel_Click);
        this.buttonOK.Enabled = false;
        this.textBoxPin.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String pattern = @"^[0-9]{4,20}$";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            buttonOK.Enabled = regex.IsMatch(textBoxPin.Text);
        };

        LoadStrings();
    }

    public void LoadStrings()
    {
       //stome stuff
    }

    public string DriverTag
    {
        get { return this.textBoxPin.Text; }
        set { this.textBoxPin.Text = value; }
    }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AssignPINForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I know it's kind of all over the place but I've provided everything I think is relevant. The middle two snippets are in the same class too, and the DB stuff is the same solution but a different project. I'd be grateful if someone can decipher what I'm after and help me out, it's the only thing I have left to do on this particular bit!

Thanks!

Comment: Is buttonAssignPIN_Click OKButton? If so, then why not just put the code that updates the database in the button click? Also, I don't think I see where you are updating the database now. I might be overlooking it.

Comment: Hi, buttonAssignPin is the button on the main form that lets you assign a pin - its the button that opens the AssignPin form essentially - not the OKButton. Details Conn (first snippet) is where the database stuff is being done.

Comment: I think the part i'm having troubles with is, " However, the database doesn't update until AFTER the editor form is closed. Therefore, I'd like to call the method that does change the database on the OKButton click, if I could." Firstly, i dont understand exactly why this is a problem. Also, what does the OKButton currently do?

Comment: `Calling an SQL stored procedure that's defined in a method using button click on form c#` - the very title of your question in itself describes a bad practice.

Comment: Perhaps it's bad practice, perhaps I'm not describing it well - but I put in all the relevant code so that it would be clear, and if it's bad practice, can you at least try to tell me what I could do better?

Comment: @killingsworth - the OK button click just goves the appearance of having changed the PIN - it removes the old one from the form and puts the new one onto the form. It's just that the physical removal doesn't take place until AFTER the form is closed, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out that even if I got that working correctly, it wasn't going to solve my problem. I've had to call a new procedure and declare that in the database schema - basically it was a lot more complicated than what I was giving it credit for. Thanks for the responses nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully got what you're after and I agree with some of the comments that this isn't the best of practice but I guess what you're after is to update the buttonOK_Click method to something like this:

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(DetailsConn connection = new DetailsConn())
    {
        int driver = -1;

        if(int.TryParse(this.DriverTag, out driver)) {
            connection.editPin(driver);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you may want to remove any other possible references to the editPin() function.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow - this seems relevant to what I asked; however, could you provide me with better practice? I'm only just out of college and I guess I'm not the most natural coder, but I'd like to know how to improve if I can! Thanks!